# Let $N = \{g \in G|gPg^{-1} = P\}$. Let $HN$ be the set $HN = \{hn | h \in H, n \in N\}$. Show that $G = HN$.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Let
$P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$.

$(a)$ Show that for all $g \in G$, there exists $h \in H$ such that $gPg^{-1} = hPh^{-1}$.

$(b)$ Let $N = \{g \in G|gPg^{-1} = P\}$. Let $HN$ be the set $HN = \{hn|h \in H, n in N\}$. Show that $G = HN$.

I have solved part a. Indeed an answer to part b.
My take-

My confusion comes; if I can say $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$?
I am proceeding as $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
$H$ is also a normal subgroup of $G$.
Let $h$ belong to $H$ and $n$ belong to $N$.
Thus $h$ and $n$ belong to $G$ as well.
$G$ is a group. Hence $hn$ belongs to $G$. Let $g$ belong $G$.
By existence of inverse $g^{-1}$ belongs to $G$.
Hence $(ghg^{-1})(gng^{-1})$ belongs to $G$.
But $ghg^{-1}$ belongs to $H$ and $gng^{-1}$ belongs to $N$.
Hence ($ghg^{-1})(gng^{-1})$ belongs to $HN$.
Hence $G$ is a subset of $HN$.

Please tell if my proof is valid. If not kindly show me a path.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No you cannot say that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. (Well I guess you can say it if you like, but it will be wrong if you do!) In fact $N_G(N)=N$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to understand that you can apply Sylow's theorems in the normal subgroup $H$ and the global subgroup $G$. Let $P \in Syl_p(H)$ and fix $g \in G$, then $gPg^{-1} \subseteq gHg^{-1}= H$, since $H \unlhd G$. But $gPg^{-1} \in Syl_p(H)$ obviously, so by Sylow's theorems, we can find an $h \in H$ with $gPg^{-1}=hPh^{-1}$. This means that $h^{-1}gP=Ph^{-1}g$, so $h^{-1}g \in N=N_G(P)$. Hence $g \in HN$. Since $g$ was arbitrarily chosen we see that $G=HN$. Again, this is called the *Frattini Argument*.